# How to use all() in python?

Tags: python

I want to check if all elements of a list are not present in a string.

ex :

```
    l = ["abc","ghi"]
    s1 = "xyzjkl"
    s2 = "abcdef"
```

So , when l is compared with s1 it should return True,
when l is compared with s2 it should return False.

This is what i tried :

```
    all(x for x in l if x not in s1) = True
    all(x for x in l if x not in s2) = True
```

I am getting True for both cases, But it should be false in second case.
Can someone please help, any solution will help, i just want to have it in a single line.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing is valid or not. all() should only check iterables like list, tuple, dict, etc. but not check conditions like the above.

Comment: Is there an alternative way of doing this using a different operator ? I know we can always compare the count and length after the comparison. Is this the only other way ?

Comment: @SinHanJinn `(x for x in y if cond)` is generator comprehension, which is also iterable. Unlike static sequences (tuple, list, dict, etc) generators can only be iterated once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is:

> Check that all elements of a list are not present in a string.

The pattern should be: `all(s not in my_string for s in input_list)`

```py
l = ["abc","ghi"]
s1 = "xyzjkl"
s2 = "abcdef"

print(all(s not in s1 for s in l))  # True
print(all(s not in s2 for s in l))  # False
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a list of True, False. But you were simply getting the matched items, so when you do an `all` on Truthy values you will get True. Instead do:

```
all([x not in s1 for x in l])
all([x not in s2 for x in l])
```

or just without list comp, because [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) accepts an iterable.

```
all(x not in s1 for x in l)
all(x not in s2 for x in l)
```

Comment: list (square brackets) is not required, but sometimes it was faster than generator comp from OP

Comment: yes `all` accepts an iterable. modified.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is:

```
all(x not in s1 for x in l)  # True
all(x not in s2 for x in l)  # False
```